# Custom debugger to debug remote/local java application

Tags: java, remote-debugging, jdi

I want to debug a remote java application using a java program(i don't mind using eclipse api in the program) but i don't want to debug it using eclipse GUI.

Any suggestion/help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the native jdb, more about this here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jdb.html

notice that the remove debugged application should be run in debug mode for you'll able to attach it.